# How to set scope in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchBar which is working fine, but I was wondering how I can set a scope and filter results based on certain criteria like: "Dogs and "Cats"

Tutorials and example code welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Interface Builder just add the scope button titles. To add them programmatically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351887/iphone-objective-c-programmatically-adding-scope-buttons-to-a-uisearchbar).

The scope buttons are indexed from 0.

Implement `UISearchDisplayDelegate` and `UISearchBarDelegate`. You will have to implement the method below (along with 2 others)

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
```

Inside the method above use `searchOption` to get the scope index the user has selected.
If your criteria has to be in string form then you should find a way to map the string to an integer value e.g use the `NSDictionary` or just manually compare `if (0 == searchOption) ...`